# После появления окна входа GitHub через git ничего не происходит

Tags: git, github

Я первый раз решил создать репозиторий, ввели эти строчки:

```
git remote add origin (мой url).git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

и на последней строчке появляется окно входа в GitHub, однако там лишь два поля: зайти через браузер и создать новый аккаунт. Я нажимаю зайти через браузер и всё. Окно закрывается и консоль просто в ожидании.
Я знаю что такой вопрос точно дублируется, однако без понятия как правильно назвать его.
[image: окно входа]

Comment: git commit -m "My first commit"

Comment: Я коммитил. Ничего не происходит. Также вызывается окно входа и закрывается если зайти через браузер.

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось, что git пытался открыть браузер по умолчанию, однако этот браузер не работал. Я изменил браузер по умолчанию на другой, все заработало.